# Insert vector into vector, Matlab

Tags: matlab

This code is to cut random values from the vector `ch` and create new vector `a`. Then, insert `a` into `ch` after delete a selected values from `ch`

What I should change, to be the result like this:

for example if `a = [8; 4; 9]`, then the result :

```
ch = 5 8 4 9 6 7
```

**Matlab code:**

```
ch = [4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9];

for i = 1:3
    g = randi(3);
    a(i) =  ch(g);
    ch(g) = [];
end;

startIdx = 2;
finalIdx = startIdx + size(a,1) - 1; 
ch(startIdx:finalIdx) = a; 

disp (ch);
```

Comment: @rayryeng, Which part is not clear?

Comment: Your code seems to run.  I don't understand what it is you want and please forgive me if I am rude, but the language in your question is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: What is the initial vector?

Comment: @R.Bergamote, This : ch = [4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9];

Comment: Do you want to randomize the order of your vector?

Comment: @shdotcom what is wrong with this code? What is the output you are getting and what is the output that you are expecting? Share these both for the community to understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: a = [5, 7, 8]; ch = [4; 6; 9]; So there is a choice to be made here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ch = [4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9];

for i = 1:3
    g = randi(3);
    a(i) =  ch(g);
    ch(g) = [];
end;

a = a'; % your problem probably come from mixing column / lines

startIdx = 2;
ch = [ch(1:startIdx); a; ch(startIdx+1:end)]; 


disp (ch);
```

Comment: when I run the code I got this output:
a= 5 6 4 
ch = 7 8 5 6 4 8 9
The second "8" should not be there, the output should be:
ch = 7 8 5 6 4  9

Comment: I have ganged this: ch(startIdx:end)];   

to:

ch(startIdx+1:end)];

and its working now. Thank you